# get child div from parent using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys I have a parent div and multiple child div. and I have a scroll which can be moved up and down to view the child. Now I want to know that is there a way that when I scroll down or up then using jquery I would see which child div is in focus. Is there any way to do that. If yes please tell. Thanks

Here is a example

```
<div id="parent" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px">
   <div id="child1">
      <p>
     some text
     </p>
    </div>

   <div id="child2">
      <p>
     some text
     </p>
   </div>

   <div id="child3">
      <p>
     some text
     </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now this becomes like this [image](http://screencast.com/t/78zJLX8q). Now as I scroll down then how can I know which child div which is in focus. Every time the user moves the scroll how will I know which div is in focus.

```
$( '#parent' ).scroll(function() {
  //What shoult I write here to know which child div is in focus 
});
```

Comment: Do you really mean "in focus", or currently visible? Not the same thing. The element that has "focus" is the one that will receive keyboard events. And what if it is scrolled so that the bottom half of one and top half of the next are both visible?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes I mean in focus or currently visible

Comment: @NewToJS I tried to use the .focus function but that doesn't works for em

Comment: @NewToJS I  have even tried the .scroll but I can't understand how will I get know which div is in focus

Comment: @garden you don't have any attempts shown in your question. I suggest you display what you have tried and try explain why you think it isn't working as intended.

Comment: I think you are looking for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: @NewToJS updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I have used a plugin called Jquery Visible in the past to achieve this. I can't describe exactly what's going on in the background of it, but you can set up a call to check if your element is within the viewport:

```
$('#element').visible()
```

I'd like to note that I haven't used the plugin in at least 12 months, so support may have ended. https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery

Comment: isn't there any other you might know because I have alot of child divs. Now if I started writing it would be alot of code

Comment: @garden Assign a `class` name rather than `ID`'s.

Comment: Using this plugin you will be able to chain classes together to get specific children, or if you're looking for your last item in the list it could be something like:

    $('#parent div:last-child')

Comment: and via this can I get some attribute of the current child div which is in focus

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any easy way to do this.
I did however find this useful function on a similar post:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

it basically checks the element off against the top of the window.

To add in your example:

```
$( '#parent' ).scroll(function() {
            $(this).children().each(function(child) {
                if(isScrolledIntoView(child)) {
                    //Do the thing
                }
            });
        });
```

See the post here: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)